# How do I align multiple images and text elements in a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Newbie web developer here working on a practice project. I'm trying to use flexbox to create a layout like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U0Q0.jpg).

So far, here's my  code:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#left {
  margin: 32px 24px;
}

#left img {
  width: 60%;
}

#right {
  width: 40%;
}

#right img {
  width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div id="left">
      <img src="./resources/images/information-main.jpg">
      <h1>H1 here</h1>
      <p>Paragraph here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <img src="./resources/images/information-main.jpg">
      <p>Paragraph here</p>
      <img src="./resources/images/information-main.jpg">
      <p>Paragraph here</p>
      <img src="./resources/images/information-main.jpg">
      <p>Paragraph here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The issues I'm having are:

- The image in the "left" div isn't resizing to 60% of the container div.
- I don't know how to get the text to align to the right of the images in the "right" div.

I know I'm having trouble with the margins also but I figured that I can probably resolve those issues once I sort out what's going on with the flexbox layout.

What am I doing wrong? Apologies if it's obvious but as I say I'm a newbie. Any and all help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: do you mean the #left image isnt matching the 60% of #left container?

Comment: `justify-content:space-between` use it in your flex container class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @UdenduAbasili It needs to be 60% width of the main .flex-container div.

Comment: @Scruffbot it doesnt work that way. The percentage is relative to the direct parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first issue. You say you want the #left image to be 60% of the main .flex-container div, so you need to set the #left to be equal to 100% of the its parent which is .flex-container and #left img to be 60% of that .

For your second issue, you want the text to align to the right of the images in the "right" div. What you need to do is add `display: flex` to the #right and the flex-direction is row by default to the text moves to the right

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#left {
  margin: 32px 24px;
  width: 100%;


}

#left img {
  width: 60%;

}

#right {
  width: 40%;
  display: flex
}

#right img {
  width: 35%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to set `width: 60%` for `#left` and then just set `width: 100%` for the nested image.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#left {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 32px 24px;
}

#left img {
  width: 100%;
}

#right {
  width: 40%;
}

#right img {
  width: 35%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="left">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U0Q0.jpg">
      <h1>H1 here</h1>
      <p>Paragraph here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U0Q0.jpg">
      <p>Paragraph here</p>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U0Q0.jpg">
      <p>Paragraph here</p>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U0Q0.jpg">
      <p>Paragraph here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#left {
  margin: 32px 24px;
}

#left img {
  width: 60%;
}

#right {
  width: 40%;
}

#right img {
  width: 35%;
}
#right .right-col-card-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
}
#right .right-col-card-container p{
  width:65%;
  margin-top:0px
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div id="left">
      <img src="./resources/images/information-main.jpg">
      <h1>H1 here</h1>
      <p>Paragraph here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div class="right-col-card-container">
        <img src="./resources/images/information-main.jpg">
        <p>Paragraph here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right-col-card-container">
        <img src="./resources/images/information-main.jpg">
        <p>Paragraph here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right-col-card-container">
        <img src="./resources/images/information-main.jpg">
        <p>Paragraph hereParagraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Please wrap your right side image & paragraph in one div & for that div add style `display:flex; align-items:flex-start`flex can make in one row & align-items:start keep inside content top of the div. also add width to your p tag which is (100% - image width(35%)) = 65%; so add this 35% width to your p tag.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Example For Easy People. Check out my code below. :)
You should use **60%** on **#left** element and then use **display:flex** on **#right** element. That's it. You will get your design like your example :)

```css
.flex-container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }
        #left {
            margin: 32px 24px;
            width: 60%;
        }
        #left img {
            width: 100%;
        }
        #right {
            width: 40%;
        }
        #right img {
            width: 35%;
        }
        #right .item {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }
        #right .item img {
            width: 40%;
        }
        #right .item p {
            width: 60%;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div id="left">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U0Q0.jpg">
            <h1>H1 here</h1>
            <p>Paragraph here</p>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U0Q0.jpg">
                <p>Paragraph here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U0Q0.jpg">
                <p>Paragraph here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U0Q0.jpg">
                <p>Paragraph here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```